# Getting imageitem values from pyqtgraph

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I am working on my first PyQt program and feel like I am missing something obvious about ImageItems or GraphicsScenes.  I have a 2d ImageItem displayed with PyQtGraph using ImageView.  My data is a numpy array.  When the mouse is hovered over a spot on the image, I am able to get x and y position values, but would also like to know the image/z/array value.  I found a similar question that showed how to get the x and y values, but not the image value.  I included the code I am currently using with PyQt4 and python 2.7 in Windows and the link to the other post.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyqtgraph/srQqVW9bqPg

```
    import pyqtgraph as pg

    self.image = pg.ImageView(self)
    self.image.show()
    self.image.setImage(data)

    self.image.scene.sigMouseMoved.connect(self.mouseMoved)

    def mouseMoved(self, pos):
        x = self.image.getImageItem().mapFromScene(pos).x()
        y = self.image.getImageItem().mapFromScene(pos).y()
```

This gets values for x and y, but I don't know how to convert them to array indices or to just get the z value in some other way.  If there is a better method than mapFromScene, that would be nice to know also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/pyqtgraph-0.9.10/pyqtgraph/imageview/ImageView.py) of `ImageView.setData`, it seems that the `image` member is used to store the data.

Even though it's a public member, it is not a nice getter property and not documented. If you don't like to use it you may need to store a reference to the data in your class. That is, make a `self.data` member.

```
def mouseMoved(self, viewPos):

    data = self.image.image  # or use a self.data member
    nRows, nCols = data.shape 

    scenePos = self.image.getImageItem().mapFromScene(viewPos)
    row, col = int(scenePos.y()), int(scenePos.x())

    if (0 <= row < nRows) and (0 <= col < nCols):
        value = data[row, col]
        print("pos = ({:d}, {:d}), value = {!r}".format(row, col, value))
    else:
        print("no data at cursor")
```

Comment: That was a great idea.  It works perfectly.  Thank you very much.